# Problems in relationships between tables in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, entity, many-to-one

I'm a little new to JPA and I'm trying to get my entity classes to work properly, but my code is always returning me this error: "Multiple writable mappings exist for the field [PRODUTOS.MARCA_IDMARCA]"

These are my entity classes:

```
@Entity
public class Marca implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer idMarca;
    private String nome;
    private Integer idFornecedores;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I'm trying to make an unidirectional ManyToOne relationship between produtos and Marca (1 Marca to Many produtos):

```
@Entity
public class produtos implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long idProdutos;
    private int codBarras;
    private String nome;
    private float preco;
    private int qtdProduto;
    private int idCategoriaProduto;
    @ManyToOne
    private CategoriaProduto categoria;
    private int Marca_idMarca;
    @ManyToOne
    private Marca marca;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Error:

```
Exception Description: Multiple writable mappings exist for the field [PRODUTOS.MARCA_IDMARCA]. Only one may be defined as writable, all others must be specified read-only.
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToOneMapping[marca]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(ClassesDeEntidade.produtos --> [DatabaseTable(PRODUTOS)])
```

I really don't know what's happening. Can anyone explain to me why this code is wrong?

EDIT:

Table definitions:

Produtos:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Produtos` (
  `idProdutos` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `codBarras` INT(13) NOT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  `preco` FLOAT NOT NULL,
  `qtdProduto` INT NOT NULL,
  `idCategoriaProduto` INT NOT NULL,
  `Marca_idMarca` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProdutos`),
  INDEX `fk_Produtos_CategoriaProduto1_idx` (`idCategoriaProduto` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Produtos_Marca1_idx` (`Marca_idMarca` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Produtos_CategoriaProduto1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idCategoriaProduto`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`CategoriaProduto` (`idCategoriaProduto`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Produtos_Marca1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Marca_idMarca`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Marca` (`idMarca`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;

Marca:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Marca` (
  `idMarca` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `idFornecedores` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idMarca`),
  INDEX `fk_Marca_Fornecedores1_idx` (`idFornecedores` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Marca_Fornecedores1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idFornecedores`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Fornecedores` (`idFornecedores`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
  ENGINE = InnoDB;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show your table definitions?
The problem seems to be that you have two fields (probably `Marca marca`, which have the `@ManyToOne` annotation and `int Marca_idMarca`, that has the same name)  mapping to the same `PRODUTO.ID_MARCA` column in the database.

I know I should post this as a comment, but I'm not able to comment yet.

Comment: I've added the table definitions. But I still didn't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: You have `int Marca_idMarca` and `Marca marca` referencing the `Marca` object, right? Do you really need this? Because you can always get the id by `marca.getIdMarca()`.

Comment: It seems like this was the problem. When I fixed this, it worked. Thanks!